# Why am I getting 'function upper(bytea)' error in python 3?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Currently I am working to convert my py-2 project in py-3 & during this conversion I have faced below kind of error.

`Partner.objects.filter(name__iexact = name_kv).count()`

When I am running above query in py2 it working perfectly & getting output '0', means getting empty list.

When I am running above query in py3 it showing below kind of error.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function upper(bytea) does not exist
LINE 1: ...alse AND UPPER("partners_partner"."name"::text) = UPPER('\x4...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I have searched lot online & SO other questions but but not able to find any solution.

I figured out that it must have been python version problem & **I am getting above error when my ORM query does not have any records**.

Comment: Can you show value of `name_kv` variable and how are you fetching it?

Comment: Now I have found that using `Partner.objects.filter(name__exact = name_kv).count()` I am not getting error so it means I am getting error because of `name__iexact`. Do you have any idea why I am getting error because of `name__iexact` Does newer version of django & python changes syntax for `iexact` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert your variable `name_kv` to string type using `str(name_kv)`.

Update your query like `Partner.objects.filter(name__iexact = str(name_kv)).count()`.

You are getting error because variable containing byte type data so converting byte data to string type may solve your problem.

Comment: If I do str(b'xyzzy') I get a string, but not a very useful one. Are you sure this works?

Comment: You shouldn't really use that solution out of the box. You are probably doing something wrong earlier in your code if you're getting bytes in `name_kv`. Investigate if what you're doing with `name_kv` before passing it to queryset is correct.

Comment: @GwynBleidD ,thanks for suggestion but I am getting `name_kv` from `request.POST.get('is_partner')` and I am getting b'on' as a value.

Comment: And that is exactly where you are making a mistake. Use Django forms to parse POST.